# Golang discord bot works in dm, but do not works in guild chat

Tags: go, discord, discordgo

Recently I decided to code my first Discord bot, and I have an issue.
When I type $help directly to bot, he sends me a message back.
However, when I send $help in discord server, I do not recieve any message back.

However, I have a function, which sends a greeting when a new user joins guild, and the bot actually sends the message.

However, it worked before, but I forget what I deleted, or added :c
Functions are completely identical, I can not figure out why it is not working.

Full code: [github](https://github.com/werniq/day-8)

Help function:

```
func help(s *discordgo.Session, mes *discordgo.MessageCreate) {
    if .Content == botPrefix + "help" {
        s.ChannelMessageSend(mes.ChannelID, message)
    }
}
```

```
func greetNewMember(s *discordgo.Session, mes *discordgo.MessageCreate) {
    if mes.Type == 7 {
        s.ChannelMessageSend(mes.ChannelID, *greetengs_text*)
     s.ChannelMessageSend(mes.ChannelID, fmt.Sprint(forTheHordeLink))
    }
}
```

Bot to should send response, both when I send message directly to it in dm, and in guild chat.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, problems was in Intents.
You should add this code in your main func:

```golang
bot.Identify.Intents = discordgo.IntentsGuilds |
discordgo.IntentsGuildMessages | 
discordgo.IntentsGuildMembers | 
discordgo.IntentsGuildPresences
```